# Mysql for Python compiler MinGW32 gcc.exe error: CreateProcess file or directory not found

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm trying to get Django/Python to work with MySQL, so I'm installing Mysql for Python adapter.

At one point, I discovered that I needed to use the MinGW compiler, so I installed that.
I encountered many annoying problems, and I managed to get past them.  This one, however, is especially torturing.

The error occurs when I attempt to execute the following command in command line for Windows:
*setup.py install build --compiler=mingw32*

Here is the error:

```
> running install<br> running build<br> running build_py<br> copying
> MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb<br> running
> build_ext<br> building '_mysql' extension<br> gcc.exe -mno-cygwin
> -mdll -O -Wall -Dversion_info=(1,2,3,'final',0) -D__version_ 
> _=1.2.3 -IC:\Server\MySQL\include -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC -c _mys ql.c -o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\_mysql.o /Z1<br>
> **gcc: /Z1: No such file or directory<br> gcc: CreateProcess: No such file or directory<br> error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1**
```

Can any of you guys help me out?

Answer (score 1):

This error is caused by /Zl parameter, as they are special parameters used only by VC. We could delete them on `setup_window.py`.

Comment: Worked for me. Just edited the setup_window.py in pip's temporary 'build' folder. This should be the answer.

Comment: How do you freeze the build folder? Once pip reports the error, the build folder is automatically deleted.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on your answer.

Comment: Where is `setup_window.py` located?

Comment: @linuxlsx What exactly is VC?

Comment: Visual studio c compiler

Answer (score 0):

Since you're talking about MinGW, I'm assuming you're building on Windows. You probably need to add the directory where mingw's gcc binary resides to your PATH.

Assuming it's C:\MinGW32, then you'd do something like:

```
set PATH=C:\MinGW32\bin;%PATH%
```

You'd do that *before* you ran `python setup.py install build --compiler=mingw32`

Comment: `gcc` must already be on his path since it's `gcc` which is causing the error

Answer (score 0):

Using compiled binaries for windows machine helps. you can get it here http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/files/mysql-python/1.2.3/